# Postgresql requests causing a timeout all of a sudden

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I upgraded my Heroku Postgres database about a week ago to a Standard plan from Hobby. Today I did the first push to production since then, and all of a sudden all of my Postgres requests are failing and causing timeouts on my app. I reverted to my last commit and the same issue is still happening. Now my app is broken.

These are the logs from Postgres:

[image]

Something that doesn't make sense to me is that Postgres is saying that no user name is specified, however I've never had this issue connecting to my database before. My database is on the same app as my server and I'm using a connection string to connect to on production like so:

```
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true
  })
```

There are no errors when creating the pool, but then when making a request to the database I get no response, no error or success and my request just times out.

Again I haven't changed anything in the code, all that happened was an upgrade to a Standard Server and then it continued to work until the next push to production.

[image]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I've been getting a lot of customer complaints today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using an old version of pg, 7.8. I upgraded to 8.5 and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue today, and in my case it was heroku deploying in node 14.x environment, which caused an issue with the "pg" module. Specifying node 12.x in my package.json fixed the issue.